# How to convert unix timetamp to date object in D3?

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to D3 and I'm trying to console.log the unix timestamps in my json file in a more readable form, such as date objects. How would I go about accessing value in the "dt" and convert that into a date object?

Here is an example of what a snippet of my json file looks like

```
"list": [
    {
        "main": {
            "aqi": 2
        },
        "components": {
            "co": 213.62,
            "no": 0.98,
            "no2": 6,
            "o3": 85.83,
            "so2": 1.89,
            "pm2_5": 4.94,
            "pm10": 11.6,
            "nh3": 0.37
        },
        "dt": 1629072000
    },
    {
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this question is tagged [d3.js](/questions/tagged/d3.js), a D3 solution is using the specifier `%s` for seconds since Unix epoch, with `d3.timeParse`:

```js
const parser = d3.timeParse("%s");
const seconds = 1629072000;
console.log(parser(seconds))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```